# Replace Value in text File with the quotient of: Value in txt file / 1000000 (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible-2.x

Created an ansible script to create text file from result of commands issued on a switch

Directory: /etc/ansible/playbooks-working-directory/intutil.txt

Lines from intutil.txt

TwoGigabitEthernet1/0/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
5 minute input rate **5000** bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
5 minute output rate **25000** bits/sec, 38 packets/sec
TwoGigabitEthernet1/0/2 is up, line protocol is up (connected) 
5 minute input rate **7000** bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
5 minute output rate **24000** bits/sec, 38 packets/sec

Then in ansible, i would like to execute a python script
that changes those values in text file to quotient of (value in text file / 1000000).

for example:

line is :
5 minute input rate **5000** bits/sec, 1 packets/sec

formula: 5000 / 1000000 = 0.005

txt file output is:
5 minute input rate **0.005** **Mega**bits/sec, 1 packets/sec

Can help to provide a python script example?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Do some research. If you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `re` (for regular expression) module:

```
import re

txt = """TwoGigabitEthernet1/0/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
5 minute input rate 5000 bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
5 minute output rate 25000 bits/sec, 38 packets/sec
TwoGigabitEthernet1/0/2 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
5 minute input rate 7000 bits/sec, 1 packets/sec
5 minute output rate 24000 bits/sec, 38 packets/sec"""

pattern = re.compile(r"\d+\s?bits/sec") # pattern to match in your text file

def repl_Mb(s):
    digits = re.split(r"(?<=\d)(?=\D)", s)[0]   # keeping only digit part
    return f"{int(digits)/1000000} Megabits/sec"

new_txt = re.sub(pattern, lambda x: repl_Mb(x.group(0)), txt)
print(new_txt)
```

Output:

```
TwoGigabitEthernet1/0/1 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
5 minute input rate 0.005 Megabits/sec, 1 packets/sec
5 minute output rate 0.025 Megabits/sec, 38 packets/sec
TwoGigabitEthernet1/0/2 is up, line protocol is up (connected)
5 minute input rate 0.007 Megabits/sec, 1 packets/sec
5 minute output rate 0.024 Megabits/sec, 38 packets/sec
```